# how to create batch file to copy files to a shared folder with full access then logs all result & errors to a file?

Tags: batch-file, xcopy, windows-xp-sp3

I have created the below batch file but no success.

```
@ECHO OFF

@ECHO "Backup process started."

@SET TARGET_FILES = "\\pc1\temp\*.mdb"
@ECHO "TARGET_FILES:%TARGET_FILES%"

@SET DESTINATION_FOLDER = "\\pc1\temp\Backups"
@ECHO "DESTINATION_FOLDER:%DESTINATION_FOLDER%"

@SET BACKUP_FOLDER = "Backup%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%"
@ECHO "BACKUP_FOLDER:%BACKUP_FOLDER%"

@SET FINAL_FOLDER = "%DESTINATION_FOLDER%\%BACKUP_FOLDER%"
MKDIR %FINAL_FOLDER%
@ECHO "DIRECTORY CREATED:%FINAL_FOLDER%"

XCOPY %TARGET_FILES% %FINAL_FOLDER% >> %FINAL_FOLDER%\%BACKUP_FOLDER%.log

@ECHO "Backup process ended successfully."

@ECHO ON
```

Environment:
It will be scheduled task in C:\Windows\Tasks using Windows XP SP3

**OUTPUT:**

```
"Backup process started."
"TARGET_FILES:"
"DESTINATION_FOLDER:"
"BACKUP_FOLDER:"
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
"DIRECTORY CREATED:"
Invalid number of parameters
"Backup process ended successfully."
```

Any guidance on the right direction is appreciated.

**UPDATES1:**
I've noticed that my variables were not set.

**UPDATES2:**

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Backup process started.

set TARGET_FILES=\\pc1\temp\*.mdb
ECHO TARGET_FILES "%TARGET_FILES%"

SET DESTINATION_FOLDER=\\pc1\temp\Backups
ECHO DESTINATION_FOLDER "%DESTINATION_FOLDER%"

SET BACKUP_FOLDER=Backup%date:~0,4%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%
ECHO BACKUP_FOLDER "%BACKUP_FOLDER%"

SET FINAL_FOLDER=%DESTINATION_FOLDER%\%BACKUP_FOLDER%
MKDIR "%FINAL_FOLDER%"
ECHO DIRECTORY CREATED "%FINAL_FOLDER%"

XCOPY "%TARGET_FILES%" "%FINAL_FOLDER%" >> "%FINAL_FOLDER%\%BACKUP_FOLDER%.log"

ECHO Backup process ended successfully.

@ECHO ON
```

**OUTPUT FOR UPDATES2:**

```
Backup process started.
TARGET_FILES "\\pc1\temp\*.mdb"
DESTINATION_FOLDER "\\pc1\temp\Backups"
BACKUP_FOLDER "Backup20120214"
DIRECTORY CREATED "\\pc1\temp\Backups\Backup20120214"
Backup process ended successfully.
```

**LOG**

```
\\pc1\temp\file1.mdb
\\pc1\temp\file1_be.mdb
2 File(s) copied
```

With the new code (UPDATES2), I have successfully copied all mdb files to target folder **but all my echo messages were not logged. How can I include all my echo messages to be logged?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need add

```
**cd /d %~dp0\**
```

("%~dp0" can replace the runtime directory to the full path of the batch file)

in your first line ..

**cd /d %~dp0 means cd /d d:\currentfolder**

**UPDATE:**

Ok , I think you just want to copy your files from  A to B .

I create a sample for you base on your code.

My folder is  at

```
D:\Run
│  main.bat  >> the copy batch
│  
└─Test
    │  new.txt
    │  
    └─Backups
        └─20120214          >> created new folder
```

the main.bat is

```
@ECHO OFF

cd /d %~dp0\

ECHO Backup process started.

SET TARGET_FILES="Test\*.txt"
ECHO TARGET_FILES:%TARGET_FILES%


SET DESTINATION_FOLDER=Test\Backups\%date:/=%
ECHO DESTINATION_FOLDER:%DESTINATION_FOLDER%

SET FINAL_FOLDER=%DESTINATION_FOLDER%
ECHO FINAL_FOLDER:%FINAL_FOLDER%
MD "%FINAL_FOLDER%"
ECHO "DIRECTORY CREATED:%FINAL_FOLDER%

XCOPY %TARGET_FILES% %FINAL_FOLDER%

ECHO Backup process ended successfully.

@ECHO ON
```

i hope it would help you .

Comment: I appreciate but sorry I can't understand it. could you elaborate it?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Additional for logs, I have created another batch file just to execute the batch file. `batchfile.bat >> %LOG_FULL_PATH%`